# Vuetify What is the child-flex option in a v-flex used for?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In the vuetify online doc  ( Grid systrem # Unique layouts ) the v-flex tag for the Orange block has a child-flex parameter

```
    <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm2 child-flex>
     <v-card color="orange lighten-2" tile flat>
       <v-card-text>ORANGE --- {{ lorem.slice(0, 90) }}</v-card-text>
     </v-card>
    </v-flex>
```

I cannot find any explanation on child-flex ... what's that ? what is the usage  ?
thanks for feedback or link to any doc paragraph  I could have missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote, there's nothing about it in the documentation and if you open developer tools you can see that the directive applies the same rules of `d-flex` (the difference is only `!important`). So I think you could remove it from your project and you will not notice any difference.

[image]

Comment: Seems like some legacy class perhaps? Because `v-flex` sets its children to `flex: 1 1 auto` anyway? Maybe it wasn't always the case in some earlier versions.

Comment: @Traxo yes, probably is something legacy. `v-flex` (as you can see on the image) set the element itself to `flex: 1 1 auto`, but not its children.

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback ! I tried to delete it and I did not noticed any change in the layout..  but I was not sure of any collateral effect later on ....